# Should I let Civilization 6 run as admin?

Tags: civilization-6

Every time I start up Civ 6, Windows 10 pops up an alert, asking my permission to let it make changes to my system.

I don't see any reason why a game should need to make such changes. Why does it need this permission? And what will happen if I refuse?

Comment: It needs to install runtime library updates. This has happened for me twice now out if the several times I've started the game this weekend. They're probably releasing day-one updates

Comment: From what I can tell, it wants to install VC library updates. These don't come out every day.

Comment: But if a game update adds a library or changes the required version of a library, then this could trigger a VC library update.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure Civ is adding a library or changing the required version of a library, every time I start it. That's why it runs a script called runasadmin.vdf, because it always needs to update a library. That's the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed it for me was deleting the _CommonRedist folder under the Civ installation folder. (That's `<steam location>\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization VI` for those unfamiliar with Steam's directory layout.)

Thanks to the discussion on this thread [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/2/558747218147609660/), as well as @Horuskol's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually - the game itself is not trying to run as administrator.

The game is trying to get some libraries installed which it requires, and this requires administrator access. Once the libraries are installed, the game will run in user mode without elevated privileges.

If you read the popup, it should be clear that it's the Steam client requesting the privileges, as it is this that is trying to install the libraries that Civilization VI needs.

Now, one reason why you may need to do this more than once is because the game is fresh out, and there were probably a small number of minor day one updates coming out in quick succession. Any change to a library requirement can cause the request for elevated privileges. (Personally, I've been asked this only twice, out of at least a dozen starts of the game from Steam over the weekend).

However - there are reports of other games getting stuck continually asking for the VC Redistribution package to be updated on startup.

https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=steam+keeps+installing+vc+redist

This seems to be some kind of client data cache issue with Steam.

Answer (score 1):

Games are generally between a rock and a hard place when they have self-update capabilities. Windows security restrictions don't allow a non-admin process to change files under Program Files. The official recommendation from Microsoft is to install under ProgramData instead but this is often unexpected by users and can be confusing. There isn't a way to ask for permissions just on your own folder. So here we are.

Comment: I installed Steam (plus all its games) into c:\games\steam, so it should be able to write anything it wants.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the escalation request has to be written in to the exe headers.